# How to differentiate between one space and multiple spaces in SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to parse a sas variable into several variables based on the the space (or special characters) between 2 words. I would like the code to place the word in a new column ONLY when there is > 2 spaces (or special chars) between the words.
for example below I have used ^ instead of space here.

```
    if TEXT="                   
            LEVEL^OF^RENAL^IMPAIRMENT^^^^^^^SEVERE,^n^(%)^^^^^^^52^(^1.9)^^^^^^^^^ 133^(^1.5)"

   then col1= "LEVEL^OF^RENAL^IMPAIRMENT"
  col2= "SEVERE,^n^(%)"
  col3="52^(^1.9)"
  col4="133^(^1.5)"
```

it would be great if the code can count the number of columns for each record upto a max of say 15 columns.........Regards, Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to convert your data in delimted file that the `scan()` function can understand.  For example this statement,

```
text2=prxchange('s/(\^| ){2,}/~/',-1,TEXT);
```

results in text2 of

```
LEVEL^OF^RENAL^IMPAIRMENT~SEVERE,^n^(%)~52^(^1.9)~133^(^1.5)
```

which is a version of your data that uses `~` as a delimeter.  Now you can use `scan()`, like this:

```
col1 = scan(text2,1,'~');
col2 = scan(text2,2,'~');
col3 = scan(text2,3,'~');
col4 = scan(text2,4,'~');
```

You might have to modify the regex to capture all the spaces and special characters that can make up a delimiter.  In my example, the `(\^| )` means "a string that is either a single `^` or a single space".  Also, if you're data contains `~` you'll probably want to choose some other characther.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to do something very similar to what you have suggested, but your code is sleeker. BTW does 's' means replace?